# How can I in SQL filter rows that only has an initial row per id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with id and state that are only written to, never updated where I want to query only the id's that have the initial state, i.e. only rows for id's with the first row written, so that I can process them for state changes down the line.
If processing goes fine a new state is written for those id's and the next time I query I shouldn't get rows with the id's that were successfully processed.

Example: I have two rows for an id with state 'INITIAL' and 'DONE' and another row for a second id with state 'INITIAL'.
When I query I want to only get the second id.

I've tried with group by but since I can't filter on the state without grouping on it too so it didn't work the way I intended.

I came up with this query but is this really how to solve it?

```
select id, state from states s1 where state = 'INITIAL' and not exists
(select 1 from states s2 where s2.state != 'INITIAL' and s2.id = s1.id);
```

I'm using Postgres btw :)

I've found many similar questions here but not exactly this, but please direct me to another answer if you know one! :)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, perhaps the most efficient, uses an `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT id, state
FROM states s1
WHERE
    state = 'INITIAL' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM states s2 WHERE s1.id = s2.id AND s2.state <> 'INITIAL');
```

We could also use aggregation here:

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.state
FROM states s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM states
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN state <> 'INITIAL' THEN 1 END) = 0
) s2
    ON s1.id = s2.id;
```

Another option is a self-join:

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.state
FROM states s1
LEFT JOIN states s2
    ON s1.id = s2.id AND s2.state <> 'INITIAL'
WHERE s1.state = 'INITIAL' AND s2.id IS NULL;
```

This query works by retaining all records where an `id` is `INITIAL`, but cannot join to another record having the same `id` with a state *other* than `INITIAL`.

Comment: The first one is the same as my attempt, right? :) But thanks! I like the having with case. Is that Postgres specific?

Comment: @ChillyPro I guess I didn't read your question very clearly.  The second option should run on pretty much any SQL database.  Which version you use is really up to you; both should have similar performance (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Since INITIAL is the first state I made a select of the id's with only 1 row (using count)

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT id, state, COUNT(*) count
      FROM states
      GROUP BY id) as c
WHERE c.count = 1 
  AND c.state = 'INITIAL'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like the fact that the state name isn't checked here in case some bug or a human error happens to delete the initial row or that it never was written.

Comment: @ChillyPro state added

Answer (score 1):

Use having cluase

```
select id from states s1 
group by id
having sum(case when state='INITIAL' then 1 else 0 end)=1
and sum(case when state<>'INITIAL' then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Comment: I don't think you need to check for the _presence_ of `INITIAL`, because if you exclude all records which are _not_ `INITIAL`, and there is still a group, it implies that the remaining record is `INITIAL`.